# Solution for $A x = b$ for every $m$-vector $b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. If $Ax=b$ has a solution for every $m$-vector $b$, then does $A^T y = c$ also have a solution for every $n$-vector $c$?

---

My teacher quickly mentioned this property, but there has no explanation or proof. Could someone provide some intuition behind this?

I understand that a pivot in every row means that Ax=b has a solution for all b, but does that apply to this?

Comment: Is the case $m=n$ admissible? Or must $A$ be non-square?

Comment: No specific mention of whether it is square or not. I assume it has to work at least for non-square matrices where m doesn't equal to n.

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but if the proposition is true then it seems to be equivalent to saying that $A$ has both full column and full row rank, i.e., $A$ is square and full rank.

Comment: The original question stated that it has a solution for mx1 column b and nx1 column c. Is that the same as saying m-vector b and n-vector c? Does that change anything?

Comment: Was it a question or a declaration? I assumed it was a question.

Comment: It was technically an exercise that our prof left for us. I assume there's something different about the wording?

Comment: The problem is that the question seems to be ill-posed. The so-called property only holds for regular square matrices.

Comment: Could you please re-explain why the property only holds for square matrices? The question itself is a true/false question, and since A is a mxn matrix, assuming it's not square, then it would be false since it doesn't hold for non-square matrices?

Comment: Well, you're supposed to do your own homework. Think of the $3 \times 2$ case. Two non-collinear vectors in $3$-space. Then think of the $2 \times 3$ case.

Comment: Yes I am trying to understand the problem so I can do the hw. If you have a 3x2 matrix, the x vector must then be 2x1 resulting in 3x1 b. For 2x3 matrix (A transpose), 3x1 y, would get a 2x1 c. Doesn't that fit the property? Unless I'm talking about something completely wrong

Comment: I would think of the column vectors. Vary $m$ and $n$. When do the column vectors span $\mathbb R^m$? When do they "fill the whole space"?

Comment: Only if the rank of that matrix is m does the column vectors span Rm. If the matrix has rank m, it doesn't imply mx1 solutions?

Comment: The solutions are always $m \times 1$, when they exist. But "exist for every" is a bit of a strong requirement. It means that you must pick the column vectors in such a way that, no matter what vector $b$ I pick, the linear system always has a solution. And in that case you "win". Thinking of it in terms of a $2$-player game can be clarifying — or not. You tell me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105988/discussion-between-space-fruiticle-and-rodrigo-de-azevedo).

Answer (score 0):

We use that $$Ax=b$$ has a solution if and only if $A$ has the same rank as $A'$ which is $A$ concated with $b$. If a solution exist for every $b$, we can conclude that $A$ has full rank. $A^T$ also has full rank and concenating another column cannot change it. Hence $$A^Ty=c$$ is solvable for every $c$.

Comment: What do you mean by "full rank" in the context of non-square matrices?

Comment: Since it can be a non-square matrix doesn't transposing it mess up the 2nd operation?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not necessarily true. Put

$$ A = \left(\begin{matrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3
 \end{matrix}\right) $$

Then $Ax = y$ is solvable for any $y = (\begin{matrix} 
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \end{matrix})^T \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ (Just put $x = (\begin{matrix} 
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & 0 \end{matrix})^T$). However, that is not the case for $A^Ty = c$, to see this consider 
$$ c = \left( \begin{matrix} 
1 \\ 1 \\1 \\ 1
 \end{matrix}  \right) $$

Comment: But it's Ax=b? b and y are different no?